# Android: How to delay show a Push notification and then call an API as the notification action?

Tags: android, rest, push-notification, alarmmanager

The requirement is that on receiving a Push notification the Android app needs to delay showing the notification as per user set timings in the app and then trigger the push notification when the timer window starts. When the user clicks on the push notification the app needs to make another API call to get all the details and then show to the user.

Just wondering if the above is possible in Android or are there any OS constraints that will prevent? I'm planning to set an AlarmManager to delay show the Push notification but would it work if the app is force closed or if the device is rebooted? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can't **delay** push notifications and their actions. That's by design, and it prevents malicious app behavior. Google specifically requires the user to click on the notification to trigger it's intent or actions.

Having said that, you do have a couple of ways to to do what you ask, but there are caveats with both of them:

**Option 1:** Send data-only push notifications instead of the full notifications. Those are designed specifically to bypass notifying the user, so when your app receives one, it can schedule a local notification at whatever time and with whatever payload you want. The downside is that data-only notifications are de-prioritized, so they won't always "wake up" your app from doze/standby, so you'll have to live with them being processed only during the OS scheduled time windows

**Option 2:** Clear the incoming push notification as soon as it comes in, and then schedule a local notification instead. This will do almost exactly what you want, but again, Google really doesn't want this behavior, so the OS will re-prioritize your app standby bucket allowance very quickly, and you'll be back to the same problem as **Option 1**. The only advantage here is that you'll have a few notifications that will actually be prioritized before your quota gets reduced, but the downside is that the user will always see a "temporary" notification for a couple of seconds before you clear it and then re-send it as the loca one